# Temporary materialization and xvalue expression

Tags: c++, temporary-objects, xvalue

[cppreference is said that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue): any expression that designates a temporary object after temporary materialization is xvalue expression **(since C++17)**.

[Temporary materialization is](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization):

> A prvalue of any complete type T can be converted to an xvalue of the
> same type T. This conversion initializes a temporary object of type T
> from the prvalue by evaluating the prvalue with the temporary object
> as its result object, and produces an xvalue denoting the temporary
> object.

What I suspect that I am not understood is that, from this quote, the temporary materialization conversion (prvalue->xvalue) produces **an xvalue denoting to the temporary object.** To clear what I am not fully understanding, I will provided a simple example:

```
const T& t = T();
```

The reference `t` is bound to prvalue `T()`. So a temporary of type `T` gets created and initialized from this prvalue; then the reference will bind to that temporary. I think the temporary looks like this: and `t` reference will bind to it:

```
T __tmp{ };
const T& t = __tmp;
```

Indeed the above two lines are happened implicitly, but in general, can I said that the expression `__tmp` in the assignment `const T& t = __tmp;` is xvalue expression?

Till now I am assuming I was true, if not, what does cppreference mean by "*any expression that designates a temporary object, after temporary materialization is xvalue expression*"? where's exactly the xvalue expression now? what does the word "**designates**" means in this context?

Comment: What version of C++ do you want an answer for?  Starting in C++17 `T t = T(1);` is mandated to be elided to `T t(1);` so no xvalue.

Comment: @NathanOliver - good point. I meant before C++17. Edit the question if you can.

Comment: I added the C++14 tag as that version is not required to elide the xvalue away, its just an option the compiler can take as long as it follows specific rules.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I think the compiler need `-fno-elide-constructors` to disable the optimization? Or it's irrelvalent?

Comment: You needed `-fno-elide-constructors` in C++14 and earlier to disable the elision if the compiler was doing so, but in C++17, the compiler is required to do the elision so the flag wont stop it.

Comment: @NathanOliver - the elision is enabled as long as the argument `-fno-elide-constructors` is not set regardless of the standard version being used.

Comment: @cpper: The concept of "temporary materialization" does not exist in C++14. It was added to C++17. In C++14, a prvalue *is a temporary*; nothing "materializes". So you need to edit your question to make it more coherent. If you want a C++14 answer, you need to cite text talking about how C++14 behaves.

Comment: @0x0 It's only allowed in specific cases though.  Before C++17, even if the compiler wanted to elide the temporary it couldn't if the object didn't have an accessible copy or move constructor.  In C++17, that no longer mattered and a prvalue could be elided even for types that cannot be moved or copied.

Comment: @NicolBolas - When you comment opposed on a question here, you are actually making people think that the question is wrong and has no answer. As possible as I can I will edit the question to be specific. The quote I cited from cppreference is actually since C++17 not until C++17.

Comment: @cpper: "*you are actually making people think that the question is wrong and has no answer*" That's because your question was wrong and had no answer as you stated it. At the time, your question was tagged C++14. And from the comments, that tag was added *precisely because* you said, "I meant before C++17." If that was a typo and you meant "after", OK, but it isn't my fault that your mistake made the question unanswerable.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I am very sorry since my question is not consistent. But does the question now is answerable ? or need any edit?

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler converts `const T& t = T();` into the AST, it looks roughly like this:

```
`-DeclarationStatement
  `-VariableDeclaration (name: t, type: const T&)
    `-InitializerExpr (type: const T, category: glvalue)
      `-MaterializeTemporaryExpr (type: const T, category: xvalue) [conv.rval]
        `-ImplicitCastExpr (type: const T, category: prvalue) [dcl.init.ref#5.3]
          `-ExplicitCastExpr (type: T, category: prvalue) [expr.type.conv]
```

(the ImplicitCastExpr is from the words "adjusted to" in [dcl.init.ref#5.3.sentence-2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.3.sentence-2))

so to answer

> where's exactly the xvalue expression now?

it's the `MaterializeTemporaryExpr` on the syntax tree. There are many such implicit conversions in C++ (and even in C, e.g. consider the AST of `1.2/2`

> can I said that the expression `__tmp` in the assignment `const T& t = __tmp;` is xvalue expression

no; that's lvalue per [expr.prim.id](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#unqual-3.sentence-7) and so it takes a very different path through [dcl.init.ref]. Also there is no assignment

Answer (score 0):

> can I said that the expression `__tmp` in the assignment `const T& t = __tmp;` is xvalue expression?

It would be better to say that the code you showed as equivalent is incorrect because it doesn't include the xvalue conversion step. A more accurate version would be:

```
T __tmp{ };
const T& t = std::move(__tmp);
```

The `std::move` cast results in an xvalue expression referring to the object `__tmp`.

> what does the word "designates" means in this context?

The same thing it means in other contexts. It isn't being used as a special term. It's just the word "designate": [to mark or point out; indicate; show; specify](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/designate). The expression `T()` indicates/shows/specifies a particular object.

Comment: And for a more complex example, the expression `std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 42)` also "designates" a prvalue (an iterator value).